# Count times a name matches a code in excel

Tags: excel

What I am trying to do is loop through a column of names (includes repeated names) and create a count of the times they appear and a call code matches.

This is my source table

```
EventID Name    Code
1811    Tom     CC,CA,CS
1809    Jane    CA,
1523    Bill    CS,CA
1637    Tom     CA,CC
1514    Jane    CS,CA,CC
1728    Bill    CC,CA
1397    Sam     CC
1873    Sally   CS
```

For example in the below table I want to match all the times Tom appears with the call code CC, in this instance 2.

```
Name    Count (CC)
Tom     2
Jane    
Bill    
Sam 
Sally
```

I can search the text to see if CC exists in the list. My source column is O in the below.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CC",O6)))
```

Cannot figure how to get it to sum for each occurrence of a person however.

Comment: `=COUNTIF(B:B,"Tom")`   ?

Comment: That only matches Tom. Not if its Tom and CC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
=COUNTIFS(L:L,L10,M:M,"=*CC*")
```

provided "CC" is limited to once per cell.